Query that only returns tags and no values
I have an InfluxDB database to log temp, pressure, humidity, and gas resistance, and it has tags for static values like location, sensor type, etc. Here's what it looks like:
> SHOW FIELD KEYS
name: environment
fieldKey       fieldType
--------       ---------
gas_resistance float
humidity       float
pressure       float
temperature    float
> SHOW TAG KEYS
name: environment
tagKey
------
host
location
sensor
serial
topic

I'm trying to create a query to return only tag values. Something like:
location   sensor    serial
---------- --------- ------
upstairs   BME280    1234
downstairs BME688    1235
basement.  BME688    1236

I can show all tags:
SHOW TAG VALUES FROM "environment" WITH KEY = "sensor"
name: environment
key    value
---    -----
sensor BME280
sensor BME680

I tried variants of this:
SELECT "location"::tag, "sensor"::tag FROM "environment" GROUP BY "location"::tag

But this isn't a legit InfluxDB query - I believe those require at least one field. Is it possible to do what I'm attempting?
I'm running InfluxDB 1.6.7
